# Android - TextSwitcher - Change TextView

Tags: android, text, view, switch-statement

I have an existing TextView (in code it's name - **quote**) and I want to change it's text with fancy animation.

It seems the only way to create an text-changing animation is to use TextSwitcher.

I try to use this code:

```
quoteSwitcher = (TextSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.quote_switcher);

        quoteSwitcher.addView(quote);

        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out);

        quoteSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
        quoteSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);

        quoteSwitcher.setText("Example text");
```

And this code throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

What can I do? I just want to change TextView text with animation.

Full code:

```
protected void initWidgets() {
    quote = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quote); // Афоризм

    /* Начальное значение афоризма */
    quote.setText(getRandomQuote());

    /* Плавная анимация смены афоризмов */
    quoteSwitcher = (TextSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.quote_switcher);

    quoteSwitcher.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    quoteSwitcher.addView(quote);

    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_out);

    quoteSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
    quoteSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);

    quoteSwitcher.setText(getRandomQuote());
}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:id="@+id/main_layout">

<TextSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/quote_switcher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextSwitcher>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/logotype_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/logotype"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/logotype"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/main_logotext"
    android:id="@+id/logotext"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="55sp" />

<TextView
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/main_quote_0"
    android:id="@+id/quote"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

Comment: Try to check if quoteSwitcher hash child then call quoteSwitcher.removeView() before quoteSwitcher.addView(quote).

Comment: check http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-textswitcher.html

Comment: could you post your xml??

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the quote `TextView` already has the parent i.e. `LinearLayout`.

You can try setting the custom `Factory` to your `TextSwitcher`

```
quoteSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {
public View makeView() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       // create new textView and set the properties like clolr, size etc
       TextView myText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
       myText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
       myText.setTextSize(36);
       myText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
       return myText;
     }
 });
```

and you can remove the quote `TextView` from the xml file and also remove `quoteSwitcher.addView(quote);`. For more detail check this [blog](http://learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-textswitcher.html).

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your code is that you are adding a textview from your xml which already have a parent view. Use the following code. In it i am creating a textview at runtime with no existing parent and adding it to textWatcher which will solve your issue.

```
mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);
    mSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {
        public View makeView() {
            // create new textView and set the properties like clolr, size etc
            TextView myText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            myText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            myText.setTextSize(36);
            myText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            return myText;
        }
    });

    // Declare the in and out animations and initialize them
    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    // set the animation type of textSwitcher
    mSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
    mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);
```